# Is there word which is better than the word Among for joining two sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

Some research suggested that we should sleep seven hours per night.
https://www.helpguide.org/articles/sleep/sleep-needs-get-the-sleep-you-need.htm

I have written some sentences in response to the above topic:

> Sentence 1: I usually spend 12 hours at home.
>   Sentence 2: I sleep 7 hours, spend 1 hour on eating and bathing, and the housework and homework occupy the remaining 4 hours.

But I couldn't think of a better word to join the sentences together. I tried to join the two sentences together using *among*:

> I usually spend 12 hours at home.  **Among** the 12 hours, I sleep 7 hours, spend 1 hours on eating and bathing, and the housework and homework occupy the
>   remaining 4 hours.

Comment: But the two sentences aren't joined together here. If you're looking for a better preposition than _among_, consider _of_: _"**Of** the 12 hours, I sleep 7 hours, spend 1 hours on eating and bathing, and the housework and homework occupy the remaining 4 hours."_ That is idiomatic.

Comment: A side note, we would normally say "I spend an hour eating and bathing" rather than **on** eating.  **on** isn't ungrammatical, but with things you do directly (rather than do *for yourself* or *to yourself*), we don't use **on**.  You might spend 15 minutes "*on* your hair".

Comment: Thank you P.E.Dant and Tᴚoɯɐuo for the useful information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a pronoun without any joining word:

> I spend twelve hours at home—seven **of them** sleeping, one eating and bathing, and the rest on homework and housework.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this...

> I usually spend 12 hours at home out of which I sleep 7 hours, spend 1 hour on eating and bathing, and the housework and homework occupy the remaining 4 hours.

Or

> I usually spend 12 hours at home. From these 12 hours, I sleep 7 hours, spend 1 hour on eating and bathing, and the housework and homework occupy the remaining 4 hours.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a great opportunity to use one of my favorite grammatical tools: the mighty semicolon!

> I usually spend 12 hours at home; 7 hours are spent sleeping, 1 hour eating and bathing, and housework and homework occupy the remaining 4 hours.

Comment: Thank you Dan Henderson! Your answer is impressive but it is too new to me, I have not learnt this in school. I need some time to learn how to use it.