# A recent report vs the recent report by HelloWorld Company, is there a rule to determine to use A or The?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Previously I asked the question about how to join two sentences together.
[Is there word which is better than the word Among for joining two sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136176/is-there-word-which-is-better-than-the-word-among-for-joining-two-sentences)

In the question, I said:

> Some research suggested that we should sleep seven hours per night.

Now I want to rewrite the above sentence this way:

> [A / The] recent report by Helpguide suggested that we should sleep seven
>   hours per night.

But I am not sure if I should use A or The for the new sentence.

Comment: Have you already mentioned the report in an earlier sentence?  If not, you would say "A recent report" and "suggests", not "suggested".  You'd  want to use "suggests" in most cases, unless, say, you're speaking of another report which has superseded the first report, or want to refer to the report in terms of some timeline.

Comment: The present tense **suggests** is a writing convention, not a grammatical issue.  It is a convention to refer to written works using the present tense when citing them.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that "suggests" works better because the report is recent, and that "suggested" could work if the report was a lot older?

Comment: Thank you  Tᴚoɯɐuo! What about if I replace suggested by showed or if I omit the the word recent, which is better?  A report Helpguide suggested that..., or A recent report showed that...

Comment: Sorry to bother you in the comment  Tᴚoɯɐuo. I think it is not good to ask a new question about whether it is grammatical to write sentence in past tense with the word, recent in the same sentence. I have asked too many questions in a single day, and I am afraid that will cause annoyance.

Comment: If possible, could you tell me if it is not grammatical to write a sentence like this: A recent report by ABC Company {showed / suggested / indicated / any verb in past tense}...

Comment: Use *a*, assuming Helpguide releases many reports, unless there is a specific focus on this report, in context. Since your topic seems to be "Some research" (more than one report), I would use *a*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not already referred to the report, then you should use the indefinite article A. This applies whether the author/publisher has issued only one report or many. You can describe the report as "recent" in both cases.

If you have already referred to this report earlier in your essay, then you should use the definite article The. In this case it is not necessary to describe it as "recent", unless you are distinguishing between two different reports by the same author/publisher.

When describing what the report suggests or shows or indicates etc, you should use the present tense when referring its implications for the present. This is clearly the case in your example. However, if you are referring to the  historical context of the report, or an effect it had which no longer applies - eg how report affected people in the past - then you should use the past tense (suggested or showed or indicated etc).